# ng-show if the directive's attribute is equal to value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a directive which I use in multiple places, however in one of the directives I need to match a value to show certain elements. The following doesn't work for me.

```
<my-directive attr="my.value"></my-directive>
```

And within the directive

```
<div ng-show="attr == 'my.value'"> Hello world </div>
```

Directive:

```
'use strict';
module.exports = Directive;

function Directive(){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'directive.html',
    scope: {
      attr: '='
    }
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You want literally `"my.value"`?

Comment: Post your directive code.

Comment: Yes - just added.

Comment: Not clear what you are trying to do. You want to check if what has been passed into directive was literally `'my.value'`? It's very easy but doesn't make sense.

Comment: Your are passing my.value to the directive so... my.value its equivalent to scope.attr inside the directive. Inside the directive my.value its undefined

Comment: Right, if using "attr" in a few places with different values, how to add condition for certain value in HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you pls try "@" for binding the value in directive it works for me

```
'use strict';
module.exports = Directive;

function Directive(){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'directive.html',
    scope: {
      attr: '@'
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The expression you use checks if `attr` scope is equal to the `string` 'my.value'.

If you want to check if it's equal to the value of `my.value` you got to use it this way.

```
<div ng-show="attr == my.value"> Hello world </div>
```

Comment: Have you injected the `$scope` attribute in your directive's controller ? Also have you defined the `attr` scope like this: `scope: { "attr" : "=" }` on your directive's definition ?

Comment: Yes I did that too,

Answer (score 0):

You have to do something like this

https://jsfiddle.net/pdhm98s3/6/

```
<div ng-app="miniapp">
   <div ng-controller="myController">
      <my-directive attr="my.value"></my-directive>
   </div>
</div>


var app = angular.module('miniapp', []);

app.directive("myDirective", function() {
  return {
        "restrict": "E",
        "replace": true,
        "scope": {
            "myValue": "=attr"
         },
        "template": '<div ng-show="myValue"> Hello world </div>'
    } 
})

app.controller("myController", function($scope) {
   $scope.my = {
      "value": 1
   }
})
```

Test it by changing the value to 1 and 0 in the controller